# A clarification on Stable Convergence of Triangular Arrays of Random Variables

Tags: random-variables, weak-convergence

Consider the following important theorem, due to [Jacod (1997)](http://www.numdam.org/article/SPS_1997__31__232_0.pdf), on stable convergence of triangular arrays of random variables. In what follows $\mathcal{F}_t$ indicates a filtration on $[0,1]$ and $t_{j,n}$ is a partition of the time-interval $[0,1]$.

[image]

My question: is it strictly necessary that the conditioning that appears in conditions from $1)$ to $5)$ is taken with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1,n}}$ ? Would the theorem still apply if, for example, conditioning with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-2,n}}$ is considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas, for example for assumption 1. Let 
$$
\tag{1'}\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb E\left[Y_{t_{j,n}}\mid\mathcal F_{t_{j-2},n}\right]\to 0 \mbox{ in probability}.
$$
If (1') holds, in order to check (1), we have to prove that 
$$
\tag{1'}\sum_{j=1}^nd_{n,j}\to 0 \mbox{ in probability},
$$
where $d_{n,j}=\mathbb E\left[Y_{t_{j,n}}\mid\mathcal F_{t_{j-1},n}\right]-\mathbb E\left[Y_{t_{j,n}}\mid\mathcal F_{t_{j-2},n}\right]$. The fact that $\left(d_{n,j}\right)$ is a martingale difference sequence can help.